# Opendaylight WebGUI not visualize topology/nodes info for SNMP devices

Tags: snmp, sdn, opendaylight

I doing experiment with Opendaylight controller and following the guideline provided.

```
https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-oxygen/user-guide/snmp4sdn-user- 
guide.html
```

The webgui no problem to visualize nodes and topology of OF devices created over mininet but failed to visualize snmp devices.

Opendaylight Boron SR4 and have install snmp4sdn features as require. I able to load switch list (as per example) and show switch list using snmp4sdn:PrintDB able to show me the list of snmp switches. I have execute topology discovery as per guideline and nothing appeared on the web gui topology view.

I really appreciate if someone here have successfully do this use case over opendaylight. Please advise me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OpenDaylight's GUI, DLUX, has been deprecated (since Fluorine or Oxygen I think) due to lack of people contributing. It's normal/recommended to stick to the REST API.

Comment: Hi..thanks..im using boron...and have curl the topology and devices but nothing return... curl --user "admin":"admin" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8181/restconf/operations/topology:get-node-list
{"output":{}}